# Gruntjs not correctly inheriting options in task

Tags: gruntjs

Below is a part of my Gruntfile. Running '$grunt msbuild:migrate:local' works fine, but '$grunt msbuild:migrate:dev' doesnt seem to be pulling in my ConnectionString property. Am I organizing things correctly for the options in inherit correctly?

```
msbuild: {
    src: ['Web Platform\Web Platform.csproj'],
    options: {
        projectConfiguration: 'Dev',
        targets: ['Clean', 'Rebuild'],
        maxCpuCount: 4,
        verbosity: 'minimal',
        stdout: true,
        buildParameters: {
            WarningLevel: 2,
            DeployOnBuild: false,
            Configuration: 'Dev',
        },
    },
    migrate: {
        // Defaults -----------------------------------------
        src: ['Migrate.msbuild'],
        options: {
                targets: ['Migrate'],
                buildParameters: {
                    DryRun: 'False',
                    Verbose: 'False',
                    RollbackSteps: '1',
                },
                verbosity: 'minimal',
        },
        // Tasks -----------------------------------------
        local: {
            // Uses defaults from above (I hope)
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                buildParameters: {
                    ConnectionString: 'Data Source=<%= credentials.aws_rds_hostname %>,1433;Initial Catalog=DevDatabase;User ID=<%= credentials.aws_rds_admin_username %>;Password=<%= credentials.aws_rds_admin_password %>'
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt doesn't support deeply nested tasks. The only thing that can run here is "grunt msbuild:migrate" (inheriting the global configuration, overridden by its own config)

See [this ticket](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/137) for example.

Comment: Thanks - seems odd that this wouldn't be supported, especially since it's not mentioned in any documentation. Do you have any suggestions for accomplishing something on this order in another way?

Comment: I would have probably used https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-config - but actually I stopped using grunt and migrated to gulp...